# Stable oxidation state for Thallium and indium

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

The first Ionisation Enthalpy for Thallium is ~ 590 KJ/mol whereas that for Indium is ~ 558 kJ/mol. But why is +1 oxidation state more stable for Tlthan In?
What are the other criteria that explain the stable +1 oxidation state of Thallium?

Comment: What happens to $\ce{In+^1}$? _How_ is it unstable?

Comment: In+1 readily oxidises to In+3 .